# PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8 error in React

Tags: tailwind-css, node-modules, create-react-app, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm trying to update my tailwindcss but I encountered this issue:

```
PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8
```

I've tried:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm i tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

But I see the above eror.
I'm curious that the error indicates that I need to have version postcss 8 or higher, then why doesn't it work while having its version "8.2.4" in "package.json".
Here is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/react-chartjs": "^2.1.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "chart.js": "^4.0.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.23.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.0.1",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^8.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Also, tried deleting `node_modules` then adding again via `npm i`
**Note:**

I don't need this version of tailwind(v2)

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

instead, I want to have tailwindcss v3.

**Edit:**

Here is how my `craco.config.js` looks like:

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
    style: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Post css for Tailwind V3.
Try this:

1. `npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
2. `npm install -D tailwindcss`

Comment: Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: Sorry, those didn't work. Please upload your carco.config,js file so I may assist you further.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question. Please have a look.